# Control my application from browser?

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf

I'm trying to get a bit more functionality out my application.

atm I have a WPF Application on the system, what I want to do is to have a website/html page to be opened on the same system, which contains controls so the WPF application can understand that it needs to change it's values since the user changed it on the web based version.

I'm thinking this isn't WCF as there won't be any server involved on the client system.

Can someone guide me on a way to do this.

Thanks

Comment: Does the web application actually need to do anything in the WPF application?  Or does it simply need to modify the backing data for that application?  ("change its values" is the phrase that caught my attention here.)  Both applications can use the same database easily enough.

Comment: You could host a webserver inside you're application with a specialised web page/port and handle requests from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nice thing to have would be a kind of "notification" of the underlying system to the WPF client when anything has changed - otherwise the client would have to poll frequently to detect changes.

One possible way to achieve this would be to add a WCF service layer that both the WPF client and the web site use to communicate with the underlying system (for example a database). As WCF supports callback contracts, the WCF service could notify the WPF client if changes are made to the underlying system through the web site, as the WCF service would "notice that".

Let's say you have a database in the background. The WPF application and the web site could both make changes to the database, but the WPF application wouldn't be notified if the web site makes changes.

Routing the changes through a WCF service, the WCF service could make the actual changes to the database and then notify all connected WPF clients that changes have been made. The clients could then fetch the new data.

Comment: Thanks for the info but I'm finding it hard understanding this, can a web service be used in someones system without the need for VS?

Comment: By "VS" you mean "Visual Studio"? You can host any kind of WCF service (be it a web service, a REST service or whatever service you like) in a Windows Service or a normal application if you like (`ServiceHost`, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicehost.aspx), of course without the need to install Visual Studio...

Comment: Thanks for that, it all makes sense now, I'll most likely be hosting it in another exe and package it with my software. Thanks again